# How to remove dom response from a loop

Tags: apex, batch, callout, dom

I have a dom class handler which I am calling from batch class. I am looping through the response to perform dml operations across certain objects. Since I have to use the response across different objects, I had to use queries inside the loop. This is causing issues since it is close to limit. I am not sure how I could remove this out of the loop. I want this code to be bulkified, but not sure how I could process the response outside the loop.

response contained 12 rows for each data element.

Here is my code

```
for (DOM.XMLNode node: grandchild.getChildElements()) {
                String paymentid = node.getAttributeValue('Name', '');
                if(paymentid=='ID')dataelementmap.put(node.getText(), grandchild);
            }
        }
        If(!dataelementmap.isEmpty()){
            for(String str:dataelementmap.keyset()){
                Map<String,String> tempmap=New Map<String,String>();
                for (DOM.XMLNode node: dataelementmap.get(str).getChildElements()) {
                    tempmap.put(node.getAttributeValue('Name', ''),node.getText());
                }
                finaldataelementmap.put(str, tempmap);

            }
        }
         for(String str:finaldataelementmap.keySet()){
            prodname='';
            Id entry;
            tempmap=finaldataelementmap.get(str);

            Act = tempmap.get('Companyname');
            AccId = tempmap.get('Company Number');
        }
            AcList.add(AccId);
            Transfer = tempmap.get('Mode');

            List<Account> act1 = [Select id,name, type from Account where Name =:Act limit 1];
            if(AccId =='' || AccId == null){
                for(Account aa: act1){
                     AcList.add(aa.Id);
                    AccId = aa.Id;
                }
            } 

            OrderDetails = tempmap.get('OrderDetails');
            List<Account> atlst = [select id, OrderApi__Primary_Contact__c from Account where Id =:AccId limit 1];  

            String st = tempmap.get('Email');

            List<Contact> ctlst = [select id, Email from Contact where Email =:st limit 1];
            if (ctlst.size()>0){
                for(Contact cont : ctlst){
                    cocnt = cont.Id;
                }
            }

     if(!Transfer.contains('System')){
            List<Opportunity> opplst=[Select Id,StageName,AccountId,(SELECT Id,Product2.Name FROM OpportunityLineItems Where Product2.Name like:prodname) from Opportunity Where AccountId =: AccId];
           if(opplst.size()== 0){
                  Opportunity opp=New Opportunity();
                        opp.Name = 'Test One';
                        opp.AccountId = AccId;
                        opp.StageName='Proposal/Price Quote';
                 Insert Opp;
               insert olineitems;
              opp.StageName = 'Closed/Signed';
               update opp;
                    }           
        else if (opplst.size()> 0){
            system.debug('Entered second');
             for(Opportunity o : opplst){
                if(o.OpportunityLineItems.size() == 0){
                     oppids.add(o);
                    if (prodname == 'Test'){
                        OpportunityLineItem olinew=New OpportunityLineItem();
                        olinew.OpportunityId=o.Id;                       

            Database.upsert(oli); 
            List<Opportunity> ooo = new List<Opportunity>();                            

            List<Opportunity> oplist = [Select Id,StageName,AccountId,(SELECT Id,Product2.Name FROM OpportunityLineItems Where Product2.Name like:prodname) from Opportunity Where AccountId=:AccId and StageName <> 'Closed/Signed'];
           if(oplist.size()> 0){

           for(opportunity oo : oplist){

                oo.StageName = 'Closed/Signed';
               ooo.add(oo);
            }
           }
            insert ocr;
             update(ooo);


 List<Opportunity> opplist = [Select Id,StageName,AccountId,(SELECT Id,Product2.Name FROM OpportunityLineItems Where Product2.Name like:prodname) from Opportunity Where AccountId=:AccId and Category__c = 'Booth Sales' and StageName = 'Closed/Signed'];             

for(Opportunity o : opplist){
                if(o.OpportunityLineItems.size()>0){
                    AcOpp.put(o.Id,o.AccountId);
                }
            }                       

   List<Order__c> solst = [select id,Opportunity__c from Order__c where Opportunity__c IN : AcOpp.keyset()];            

                       if(solst.size()>0){

                for(Order__c so : solst){                    
                    if(so.Status__c <> 'Closed'){
                        so.Status__c = 'Closed';
                        ids.add(so);
                    }
                }

             update ids;
                    for(Order__c so : solst){
                        if(so.Status__c == 'Closed' && so.Posting__c <> 'Posted'){
                            so.Posting__c = 'Posted';
                            idsfinal.add(so);
                        }
                    }
                }
                update salesidsfinal;

  List<Invoice__c> invlst = [select id, Order__c,Account__c,Balance__c,Status__c from Invoice__c where Order__r.Opportunity__c IN : AcOpp.keyset() and Balance__c > 0];                      

                        for(OrderApi__Invoice__c inv : invlst){
                           insert payment;
                       }
                        }
SOQl for payment;
insert payment lines;
update payment;
} //loop ends here for finaldataelement map
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all split your method into few smaller methods. Make your code easier to read and understand.

Second. Apex DOM API is not very convenient. If you work a lot with DOM try to use some third party lib like this https://github.com/JenniferSimonds/apex-xpath

Just write xpath query and get your data easily.

Some examples of xpath queries:

- [@id='w3c_home_upcoming _events'] - get any element with id = w3c_home_upcoming_events
- div[@id='w3c_home_upcoming_events']/p/a - find all **a** tags inside **p** tag inside **div** with id = ...

Work with this library for sure will free you from many **for** loops as you won't write nested loops in order to get required Nodes anymore.